# SQL left join with clause where on right table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I need to request customer on database with multiple criteria.

In my database, I have 3 tables

Customer :

```
id
nom
prenom
...
```

Contact :

```
id
valeur
customer_id
```

In my criteria of request, I have : valeur

This is the request :

```
select client0_.id as id1_6_
from client client0_ 
inner join entite entite1_ on client0_.entite_id=entite1_.id 
left outer join client_adresse clientadre2_ on     (clientadre2_.client_id=client0_.id) 
left outer join client_contact clientcont3_ on (clientcont3_.client_id=client0_.id) 
where (entite1_.numero_licence in ('ZB230EC')) 
and (upper(client0_.nom) like ('%'||upper('')||'%')) 
and (client0_.prenom is null or upper(client0_.prenom) like ('%'||upper('')||'%')) 
and (clientcont3_.valeur like ('%'||'@mail'||'%')) 
and (client0_.date_creation_sys is null or client0_.date_creation_sys>='2017-01-01') 
and (client0_.date_modification_sys is null or client0_.date_modification_sys>='2017-01-01') 
and (client0_.date_suppression is null or client0_.date_suppression>='9999-12-12')
```

This request return me customer which have not contact also my request ask customer with contact "valeur" contain "@mail"

Sample data

Customer

```
id  | nom     | prenom 
375 | aurelie |  lilie
389 | t(      |
```

In Contact

```
id    |  valeur             | customer_id
2740  |  aurelie@mail.com   |  375
2739  |  06 06 06 06 06     |  375
```

If I launch request with search :

```
    contact.valeur like '%@mail%'
and customer.nom like '%%'
```

My result is OK

But with :

```
    contact.valeur like '%%'
and customer.nom like '%t(%'
```

I have empty result

Can you help me?

Comment: Add some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: its sounds expected when using a left join. See [this](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/)

Comment: @JGH I don't think so.. I don't understand why the request return me result which expect not criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some pieces that explain this:

- First of all, you are doing a left join with these tables, so having or not data in the contact/address tables won't reduce the number of records in the output.
- If you were waiting to receive nothing because of the filters that you applied, you must know that the behaviour filtering a table in the join condition is not the same than filtering the table in the where condition:

  - Filter applied in a join: the filter is done before proceeding to join the tables
  - Filter applied in a where: the filter is done after joining the tables

Therefore, if you want to get nothing, just move your filter in the "join part" to the "where part".

**Edited answer**

Just to explain my comment...

```
with customer as (
  select 375 as id, 'aurelie' as nom, 'lilie' as prenom union all
  select 389, 't(', null
),
contact as (
  select 2740 as id, 'aurelie@mail.com' as valeur, 375 customer_id union all
  select 2739, '06 06 06 06 06', 375
)
select *
from customer cs
  left join contact c
    on cs.id=c.customer_id
where c.valeur like '%%'
  and cs.nom like '%t(%'
```

This return nothing, because you are comparing NULL with `like '%%'`

If you replace this `where c.valeur like '%%'` by this `where c.valeur is null`, you will get the record you are looking for.
If you want to continue using this `where c.valeur like '%%'` always, you will need to convert the nulls to some string, for example an empty string `where isnull(c.valeur,'') like '%%'` and it should work too.
Hope it helps, you can test it [from here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf5c9a565609a483cee559253221aea8)

Comment: Your problem is because you are comparing `NULL` with `contact.valeur like '%%'`. Your `nom` `t(` doesn't join with the rest of tables, so it has `NULL` in the `contact.valuer`. Any comparison with `NULL`, returns false, even `NULL=NULL` (except `[field] is null`). Your filter `contact.valeur like '%%'` works with any string, except with a `NULL`.

Comment: Ok I understand. I must build query according criteria. If I not have "valeur" value critera I do not left join, exact?

Comment: To be honest, I don’t know well what do you want to get. Anyway, I think all your problems here come from the explained, so you have just to apply it where proceed to get what you want

Comment: I want to select data with multiple criteria, and all criteria are inclusive. But if I want a customer with a name, and this customer has no contact, I want him in mu result

Comment: Review my answer, if that’s your purpose, I explain how to do it (replace null by empty string)